# What ERP's have a decent Ruby Connector or thorough API built?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erp, odoo

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer looking for an open source ERP which has a Ruby connector or a very robust, thorough API I can use.

I know Ruby has XLSuite, but it seems kinda outdated and am just exploring other platforms.

The closest I've found so far is OpenERP + the OOOR gem.  My concern with OpenERP is the number of bugs and problems people have posted - my sole reason of using a ERP to start with and not building anything custom, is so I don't have to fix core bugs on the platform and focus on customization.

Of course if this doesn't exist, the alternative is to access alot of the ERP functions through the API.  If this is the case, any recommendations on an ERP which has a very thorough, stable API?

Answer (score 2):

OpenERP can be accessed by xml-rpc. Here is an example in Ruby:

Login:

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'

database = "terp"
username = "admin"
password = "admin"

socket = XMLRPC::Client.new( 'http://localhost', '/xmlrpc/common', 8069 )
user_id = socket.login( database, username, password )
```

Search (after a successful login):

```
socket = XMLRPC::Client.new( 'http://localhost', '/xmlrpc/object', 8069 )
ids = socket.execute(
    database, user_id, password,
    'res.partner', 'search', []
)
partners = socket.execute(
    database, user_id, password,
    'res.partner', 'read', ['name']
)

for partner in partners:
    print "partner: %s" % [ partner['name'] ]
```

Comment: tried this but get an error of unidentified method login when i try to login